# Firebase android proxy setting

Tags: java, android, proxy, firebase

I have made an android app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.confesco.maggi
which works with firebase as database which works well when I use 3G net.The problem occurs when I use it under a proxy of our college it doesnot get connected to the database.Is there any way I can get around with this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is currently no workaround for using the Android client over a proxy, sorry. I've put this on the Firebase feature list and hopefully we can address it in the near future.

Comment: @Kato any updates? The question very actual in Russia now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no workaround for using the Android client over a proxy, sorry. I've put this on the Firebase feature list and hopefully we can address it in the near future.

(Answer copied from a previously posted comment)

Comment: Still doesnt look like there is any progress. The only thing i found was: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1036 but without any informations.. 
As @Yusufk answers article says it is not possible at the moment

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://medium.com/devopslinks/firebase-accessing-firestore-and-firebase-through-a-proxy-server-c6c6029cddb1) seems to suggest that it is possible. It applies the standard Java proxy directives and one specific one for Google API:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
System.setProperty("com.google.api.client.should_use_proxy", "true");
```

Comment: The article explicitly says that these settings won't work for the Firebase Realtime Database: "These SDKs use WebSockets to communicate with RTDB. Currently there’s no way to configure the SDKs to send this traffic through an HTTP proxy."