# Data not being saved to Firebase from Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an existing application that I am trying to convert to use Firebase Database.   Here is some code that I am using when I try to save an Object:

```
...
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference waypointRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    waypointRef = database.getReference(Utils.WAYPOINT_REFERENCE);

    waypointRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            FBWaypoint wp = dataSnapshot.getValue(FBWaypoint.class);
            wp.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Child Added:  %s, %s, %s, Prev: %s", wp.getName(), wp.getLatitude(), wp.getLongitude(), previousChildName));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            FBWaypoint wp = dataSnapshot.getValue(FBWaypoint.class);
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Child Changed:  %s, %s, %s, Prev: %s", wp.getName(), wp.getLatitude(), wp.getLongitude(), previousChildName));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FBWaypoint wp = dataSnapshot.getValue(FBWaypoint.class);
            wp.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Child Removed:  %s, %s, %s, Prev: %s", wp.getName(), wp.getLatitude(), wp.getLongitude()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            FBWaypoint wp = dataSnapshot.getValue(FBWaypoint.class);
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Child Moved:  %s, %s, %s, Prev: %s", wp.getName(), wp.getLatitude(), wp.getLongitude(), previousChildName));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to add Child Listener.", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

After creating an object, I save it like this:

```
waypointRef.push().setValue(wp);
```

I do see the callbacks firing in my logs at this point (along with values for the ids generated by firebase:

```
Child Added:  Hrbrbe, 44.969846, -89.670527, Prev: null
Child Added:  Hdbece, 44.956019, -89.666436, Prev: -KInIzqk6m96lwVWF6Pc
Child Added:  Hebdbr R, 44.970372, -89.673188, Prev: -KInJ17sfsQ4v_fUrAW3
```

However, I don't see anything in the firebase console for these records.   Also when I restart the app, the onChildAdded callback does not get fired.

I also created another app, that just contains the code above...and that works fine.   So I am not sure if something I am doing in my existing application is impacting firebase?   However, I am not sure what that could be as I also took all of my dependancies and put them in the simple project as well.

Any ideas on what I can check next?

UPDATE:   I added the onComplete Listener as recommended.  It never gets called.   If I add a FirebaseDatabase.purgeOutstandingWrites() after the setValue(), then the onComplete gets called with the following error:

```
DatabaseError: The write was canceled by the user.
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to add a completion handler to `setValue()` to see if it ends with an error. Tha will allow you to log any potential problems that the database reports (e.g. to logcat). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#receive_a_completion_callback

Comment: Correction to my previous comment (which is now deleted).  The onComplete was not getting called at all.  See UPDATE in main question.

Comment: This last bit sounds like you don't have a connection to the database. Is disk persistence enabled in your app? If so, can you see if things change when you disable that?

Comment: I did not have disk persistence enabled.   I did add it, and it seemed to behave the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just figured it out.   Thinking that there was a difference between my two projects was a red herring.   The actual difference was between the two devices that I was deploying the two projects to.  The working device was on a cellular connection.  The device that wasn't working was on our corporate wifi network behind a proxy.

I do have the proxy set up correctly on the device, and I can access external sites...however, it looks like firebase does not use the proxy settings [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805368/firebase-android-proxy-setting).

Would be great if Firebase would use device proxy settings!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep in mind, if you're saving a customized class, you need to set getters and setters for the objects which you want be saved in the firebase. If you don't, the objects which don't gave getters and setters won't be saved.