# Firebase anonymous authentication failure through Mobile Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having problems with Firebase authentication when device is connected through Mobile Data connection. If connected through WiFi authentication works fine.

I am using following code for authentication:

```
public class MyAuthActivity extends Activity
{
    protected FirebaseAuth auth;
    protected FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;

    protected FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
            {
                user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("APP", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: " + user.getUid());
                }
                else
                {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("APP", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };
        auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);

        auth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.w("APP", "signInAnonymously failure: ", e);
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        Log.d("APP", "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Log.w("APP", "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });


    }
}
```

Error received when connecting through Mobile Data:

> signInAnonymously failure: 
>                                                   com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as
>   timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
>                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblv.zzce(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd.zzcf(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbly$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Is there anything I can do to solve above issue or get more information about what is really causing problems.

Mobile phone otherwise works well through Mobile Data and is successfully accessing Internet and Google Play Store.

Firebase version 10.2.0, Android API 19

---

Some additional information. Primary purpose of above authentication is access authentication for Firebase database.

If I allow non-authenticated access to database, I can connect and retrieve data through any kind of connection (Mobile Data and WiFi). Authentication is the only part that unexpectedly fails.

Comment: did your problem still up ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua Yes.

Comment: @PN10 Did you even read the question. Everything works through WiFi connection, but it fails only through Mobile Data. Of course, anonymous login is turned on.

Comment: Have you tried to use mobile data connection of different operator?

Comment: @azizbekian No, because I currently only have access to one operator. If by any chance operator is somehow to blame then I would also like to know how to prove (debug) that. Question is why only authentication fails and why only through mobile data?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, Firebase has limitation on proxies. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805368/firebase-android-proxy-setting#comment35070430_22805368) comment from a member from Firebase team. Maybe your mobile connection uses proxies.

Comment: @azizbekian No proxies AFAIK. And if proxy would be an issue then I would not be able to connect to database, too.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar what happens when you `signInWithCredential` to firebase on Data connection?

Comment: @Mr.Arjun `signInWithCredential` also fails on mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

Found a previous answer might be related

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397853/2735586

Firebase doesnt restrict any internet connection

Can you check the status of the mobile data connection using the following (code taken from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#check-connection)

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
...
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();

Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

check this for non-authenticated & authenticated access to DB to help you debug