# firebase android app not working with mobile data

Tags: android, firebase

My Firebase Android app is not working whenever I connect with mobile data. All features such as auth, database and storage are unreachable. I am currently in India, using an Aircel sim. Is the problem from Firebase server or my network provider.

Error in logcat says:

> Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Works on wifi though, dunno why

Comment: Maybe it's related with your carrier.

Comment: I added broadband connection and now my firebase hosted angular 9 project is not working and i am using firebase as backend when i switch to old internet it is working and the diffient between two network providers the working network showing my location as another state and the new connection is showing my currect location

Comment: Same issue in 2023. Any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase server does not have any restrictions on internet connection. This would be your mobile internet provider's issue. Also, it would be worth checking whether have any settings in mobile device is enabled to restrict mobile data usage for any specific apps like to use Wifi only.

PS:  I'm from India, use Airtel and Vodafone mobile data connections often for Firebase based apps when Wifi is not around . But occasionally faced similar issues when don't have sufficient signal range especially changes to 2G.

Comment: I could solve the issue ( for Indian users ), by changing the network operator: Go to **Settings > Connections > Mobile Networks > Network Operators > Select Automatically**

Answer (score 1):

I got same kind of problem, (images are not downloading from Firebase Storage, over mobile data) using from Bangladesh.

So,I mailed it to 'Firebase' & they give me these solution, "Please, try to use a VPN, in similar cases like this it worked and reduced the scope of the issue."

Then, I used VPN with my Mobile data & everything worked fine. :)

Comment: But this is not a proper solution. Did you find a solution without VPN?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely from your network provider. I think you might have a very bad network or still, check to see if the date and time of the emulator you are using to run your application is correct if not correct it. Firebase is not suppose to give you that kind of error as firebase could also sometimes be accessible even when your device is not connected to the internet.

Comment: I am testing on my physical device but like you said, it could be my network provider. Thanks everyone

Comment: That's okay. Anytime

Answer (score 0):

In case, you are facing such problem you can simply go to mobile network >> access point names >> check GPRS button and try to change the access point names from the drop down list.  Switch off your data and then on. You can reboot your phone if there is still any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by activating the use of google play services mobile data, in configuration, apps, use of mobile data

Answer (score 0):

Check data restrictions of

> Google Services

If you are on **restricted data mode** of Google services, your application will not work. I solved it by disabling the restriction mode.

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below before declaring `databaseReference` and it worked well

```
/*Enable offline access to the data from the Cloud and synchronise when the network connection is established again*/
     
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```