# firebase auth with email and password doesnt work with mobile data connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I do firebase authentication with email and password work fine when i have wifi but i connected mobile data connection firebase authentication fail and get this message:

```
"a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable 
host) has occurred."
```

this is my gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Only WiFi work fine. Mobile data connection doesn't work

Comment: please check your permissions in your manifest

Comment: Does your Android client use proxy? I found a duplicated thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805368/firebase-android-proxy-setting#comment35070430_22805368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has limitation on proxies. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369063/5049244) comment from a member from Firebase team. Maybe your mobile connection uses proxies

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with permissions missing in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: No. I have already that permission in my manifest. When i have WiFi, i can create new user and sing In but doesn't work with mobile data connection. I try with different mobile data providers in my country but i get the same problem